# ¿Cómo actualizar el rol de usuario sin necesidad de reloguear?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Necesito actualizar el rol del usuario logueado. O sea, con el usuario logueado le asigno un nuevo rol pero no me lo reconoce hasta que me deslogueo y vuelvo a hacer el login.

Éste es mi código:

```
public static void AddToRol(string email, string roleName) {
  CheckRole(roleName); 
  var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(userContext)); 
  userManager.AddToRole(userManager.FindByEmail(email).Id, roleName); 
}
```

Al iniciar la sesión no se le asigna rol alguno al usuario, el mismo inicia mediante fuentes externas, ya sean google o faceook, tambien lo puede hacer mediante registro de usuario de toda la vida. 
En el momento de completar el registro de usuario, (entiendase usuario como una entidad de mi solución), es que le asigno un rol determinado, ya estando logueado dicho usuario. Lo que necesito es luego de asignado el rol que me permita ejecutar acciones, pos supuesto controladas mediante autorize(Roles = "User")
aqui el codigo de registro

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterNewOwnerViewModel collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            var model = new CP_Owners()
            {                    
                Rank = collection.Rank,
                Address = collection.Address,
                Email = User.Identity.Name,
                First_Name = collection.First_Name,
                ID_Plan = collection.ID_Plan,
                ID_State = collection.ID_State,
                ID_Title = collection.ID_Title,
                Name = collection.Name,
                Phone = collection.Phone                    
            };
            repo.Add(model);
            UsersHelper.AddToRol(User.Identity.Name, 
WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RoleOwner"]);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
```

Comment: Coloca el código que tienes :D

Comment: public static void AddToRol(string email, string roleName)
        {
            CheckRole(roleName);
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(userContext));
            userManager.AddToRole(userManager.FindByEmail(email).Id, roleName);
        }

Comment: ¿y en qué momento asignas el rol a la sesion? Coloca todo el código que creas que se necesite para reproducir tu escenario :D

Answer (score -1):

intenta modificando el `Identity` `Clain`

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "MyNuevoRol"));
```

Comment: Gracias. Lo pruebo luego y le digo. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, la solucion me resolvio parte del problema, adjunto parte del codigo.                 
    userManager.AddClaim(userManager.FindByEmail(email).Id, new 
    Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleName));